# Trouble with ACF sorting

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am having an issue sorting by ACF. I want to sort them alphabetically, but my query doesn't change the order at all.

Thanks in advance

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'sale',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'sales_status',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',

));
if( $the_query->have_posts() ):

while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `order => 'ASC'` in arguments like this.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'sale',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'sales_status',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
));
```